# How to transform JSON with field x,y to GDB in FME

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, fme-form, json, spatial-etl

I have JSON file with x,y field. I wonder how to transform geometry to GDB?

Example of JSON:

```
[
{
    "OBJECTID": "1",
    "x": "15",
    "y": "21"
},
{    
    "OBJECTID": "2",
    "x": "16",
    "y": "21"
},
{
    "OBJECTID": "3",
    "x": "16",
    "y": "21"
}
 ]
```

I try use GeoJSON and JSON reader. JSON reader read attributes but I don't now how to insert x,y to shape field in GDB.

Now I create table with field contains WKT. How to convert table with field containing WKT to geometry layer?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried so far? Could you also add any other information that is relevant to your question? A sample from your file can help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the JSON Reader and then use a VertexCreator transformer. This transformer (which was previously called the 2DPointReplacer) will let you convert the X/Y coordinate values into a true spatial feature.

Then you can simply write the data to your Geodatabase Writer. Make sure the Allowed Geometries field is set to geodb_point

[image]